# How to bucketize a column using another table in Bigquery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column `grams` in the table `info` which can be any positive integer. 
Also, I have table `map` which has two columns `price` and `grams`, in which grams can take some discreet values (~lets say 50) and are in ascending order.

I want to add a column in table `info` named `cost` by fetching `price` from table `map` such that `info.grams` <= `map.grams`(smallest). In other words, I want to bucketize my `info.grams` based on discreet values of `map.grams` and fetch values of `price`.

What I know?

I can use `CASE WHEN` to bucketize `info.grams` like below and then join two tables and fetch `price`. But since the discreet values are not limited I want to find a clean way of doing it without making my query a mess.

```
CASE WHEN grams<=1 THEN 1
WHEN grams<=5 THEN 5
WHEN grams<=10 THEN 10
WHEN grams<=20 THEN 20
WHEN grams<=30 THEN 30
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use [RANGE_BUCKET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#range_bucket) function for this

```
#standardSQL
SELECT i.*, 
  price_map[SAFE_OFFSET(RANGE_BUCKET(grams, grams_map))] price
FROM `project.dataset.info` i,  
(
  SELECT AS STRUCT 
    ARRAY_AGG(grams + 1 ORDER BY grams) AS grams_map,
    ARRAY_AGG(price ORDER BY grams) AS price_map
  FROM `project.dataset.map`
)
```

You can test play with above using sample data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.info` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS grams UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 7 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 10 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 13 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 15 
), `project.dataset.map` AS (
  SELECT 5 AS grams, 0.99 price UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 1.99 UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 2.99 
)
SELECT i.*, 
  price_map[SAFE_OFFSET(RANGE_BUCKET(grams, grams_map))] price
FROM `project.dataset.info` i,  
(
  SELECT AS STRUCT 
    ARRAY_AGG(grams + 1 ORDER BY grams) AS grams_map,
    ARRAY_AGG(price ORDER BY grams) AS price_map
  FROM `project.dataset.map`
)
```

with result

```
Row grams   price    
1   1       0.99     
2   3       0.99     
3   5       0.99     
4   7       1.99     
5   10      1.99     
6   13      2.99     
7   15      2.99
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it would be nice to use standard SQL for this, with `lead()` and `join`:

```
select i.*, m.*
from info i left join
     (select m.*, lead(grams) over (order by trams) as next_grams
      from map m
     ) m
     on i.grams >= m.grams and
        (i.grams < next_grams or next_grams is null);
```

However, one limitation of BigQuery is that it does not support non-equi outer joins.  So, you can convert the `map` table to an array and use `unnest()` to do what you want:

```
with info as (
      select 1 as grams union all select 5 union all select 10 union all select 15
     ),
     map as (
      select 5 as grams, 'a' as bucket union all
      select 10 as grams, 'b' as bucket union all
      select 15 as grams, 'c' as bucket 
     )
select i.*,
       (select map
        from unnest(m.map) map
        where map.grams >= i.grams
        order by map.grams
        limit 1
       ) m
from info i cross join
     (select array_agg(map order by grams) as map
      from map
     ) m;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gordon's Mikhail's answers. I would like to suggest a third alternative, using [FIRST_VALUE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#first_value), which is a built-in method in BigQuery, and the knowledge of [window](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_window_frame).

Starting from the principle that if we use [LEFT JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left_outer_join) between the info and map tables using grams as the primary key, respectively, we would have null values for each gram whose is not specified in the map table. For this reason, we will use this table (with the null values) to price all the grams with the next available price. In order to achieve that, we will use FIRST_VALUE(). According to the documentation:

> Returns the value of the value_expression for the first row in the
>   current window frame.

Thus, we will select the first non null value between the current row and the next non-value row for each row where price is null. The syntax will be as follows:

```
#sample data info
WITH info AS (
  SELECT 1 AS grams UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT 13 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT 16 UNION ALL
  SELECT 18 UNION ALL
  SELECT 19 UNION ALL
  SELECT 20 

), 
#sample data map
map AS (
  SELECT 5 AS grams, 1.99 price UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 2.99 UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 3.99 UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 4.99
), 
#using left join, so there are rows with price = null
t AS (
SELECT i.grams, price
FROM info i LEFT JOIN map  USING(grams)
ORDER BY grams
)
SELECT grams, first_value(price IGNORE NULLS)OVER (ORDER BY grams ASC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS price 
FROM t ORDER BY grams
```

and the output,

```
Row grams   price
1   1        1.99
2   2        1.99
3   3        1.99
4   4        1.99
5   5        1.99
6   6        2.99
7   7        2.99
8   8        2.99
9   9        2.99
10  10       2.99
11  11       3.99
12  13       3.99
13  15       3.99
14  16       4.99
15  18       4.99
16  19       4.99
17  20       4.99
```

The last SELECT statement perform the action we describe above. In addition, I would like to point that:

> `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`: The window frame ends at the end of the
>   partition.

And

> `CURRENT ROW` :The window frame starts at the current row.